# Tool for generating the ASP.NET MVC Controller/Action interface?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there some tool I can use to document (i.e. generate HTML or XML docs for) my ASP.NET MVC 3 application's controller/action/datatypes interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) a shot

Answer (score 2):

MVCScaffolding ( http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/) can generate anything in ASP.NET MVC. Its power is template customization which generates not only necessary actions but also views, models, and so on as you exactly want.